# Tensorflow with genetic algorithms

Tags: tensorflow

I need to use a deep neural network with a genetic algorithm where I will start all the weights with random values... the net won't "learn" at least not by training but by natural selection...
 etc.
I have used Tensorflow for training data long time ago, so this might sound stupid but should I use Tensorflow for that kind of project too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer -- you shouldn't do it -- But if you really want to do it, I think it's possible...

TensorFlow is focused on building tensor computational graphs which can calculate tensors in parallel (which decreases computational time), but using a genetic algorithm is mostly base with crossover algorithm mutation which is much more expensive to compute than multiplying or adding tensors. Moreover, neural networks tend to have millions of parameters, which makes it much more difficult if you want to load all the parameters and create a mating pool -- which will take **FOREVER** just to compute the next generation.

Answer (score 0):

Genetic algorithms have been used in neural nets, here is a good book on it

Practical Neural Network Recipes in C++
ISBN 0-12-479040-2 is a good book.

A challenge is it might not find a good solution due to too few crossovers in the genome breeding, and how to efficiently represent those neural network weights well in the genome. The above book used grey code values and a binary genome. In my experiments I used floating point values 'merging' some weights across the two parents by picking a value randomly between that weight in both parents.

Unlike jumping in bed, when two parents get together it is best to keep the TWO children created by a crossover, so good features cannot be lost through a few unfortunate breeds.

If you code in C# here is a non-tensor flow library I just found https://github.com/colgreen/sharpneat

I did have a go at a (NON-tensorflow) genetic algorithm myself, to solve a problem where backpropagation could not find a good solution. Unfortunately the genetic algorithm did not produce sufficiently good results (but did converge) .. I think my problem was noise in my input and very small features in the signal. I've published that project is here.. https://gitlab.com/yorkshireandrew/bodyscanner   (scanner2 branch)

you could maybe pull the neural net bits to experiment with.

Be warned though as Ronakit says genetic algorithms do take ages and ages, and if the initial population is too small to cover the problem space adequately after the wait you still will get a bad result. I do think it is something worth trying, but only if the function your trying to optimise is noisy and complex, as at least it will produce some kind of result.

If someone does write a good genetic optimiser for https://keras.io/ that would be really cool. Let me know if you do!